# Unable to set routes for my API in nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, express

Routes are not showing up like /courses.

This is the code in my app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

const app = express();

const courses = require("./routes/api/courses");


//connectDB
connectDB();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello world!'));


//using routes
app.use('api/courses', courses);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8082;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

And this is code in routes/api/courses

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const course = require("../../models/Course");

// @route GET api/courses
// @description Get all courses
// @access Public

router.get('/courses',(req,res)=>{
  res.send('Courses are connected!');
})

module.exports = router;
```

It it not showing up in /courses in localhost/courses.
output there is:
Cannot get /courses

I am a beginner in nodejs express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you're expecting your server to respond to:

```
http://localhost/courses
```

but you show code that defines a route for:

```
http://localhost/api/courses/courses
```

When you do this:

```
app.use('api/courses', courses);
```

You're telling Express to send any request to the `courses` router whose path starts with `/api/courses`.  So, right away, nothing will get sent to that route unless it starts with `/api/courses`.  That already rules out `http://localhost/courses`.

Then, in your `courses` router, you define this:

```
router.get('/courses',(req,res)=>{..}
```

That means you're defining a route for:

```
http://localhost/api/courses/courses
```

The first `/api/courses` comes from the `app.use()` that registers the router.  The second `/courses` comes from this route definition.

---

If you want it to respond to:

```
http://localhost/courses
```

Then, you should change this:

```
app.use('api/courses', courses);
```

to this:

```
app.use(courses);
```

That will send all possible paths to the courses router where it's check for `/courses` will result in a top level route handler for

```
http://localhost/courses
```